# TV series in 70s - 80s about a lady ghost and a young man

Tags: story-identification, tv, ghost

TV series in 70s - 80s about a beautiful lady ghost living in a big old house or castle.

The male lead is a young artist or something.  He found the old house and moved in for free (or for a very low price).  The lady ghost is always wearing the same long elegant dress. Being a ghost, she can go straight through walls.

The young man has no idea for quite a while that the lady is a ghost.  He falls in love with the ghost lady. The lady has some magic power and loves to help others.

Sadly I don't know what language it was in. Because it had been translated all into Chinese. And I am one hundred percent sure it was not a movie. Now many people in Shanghai remember the show. But the Chinese version can not be found anymore.

Comment: Do you remember what country, or what TV network, broadcast the series? What language was it in?

Comment: Similar basis to "The ghost and Mrs Muir" which has a 1968-1969 TV series based on a 1947 film. Not an answer because the ghost is a man and the live person is a lady.

Comment: *Vaguely* similar to [The Ghosts of Motley Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghosts_of_Motley_Hall) - but it's a long shot.

Comment: Maybe an episode of *[Rentaghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rentaghost)*?

Comment: If it was a film and not a TV show, maybe *[High Spirits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095304/)*? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTf25FJdGYI)

Comment: @Masuly - In roughly which year (or range of years) did you actually watch this? I ask, because from the wording you used, it's not clear whether you watched this in the '70s or '80s, or if you watched it more recently and just think it was made around that time.

Answer (score 9):

***[Jennifer Slept Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Slept_Here)*** aired in 1983, lasted just one season on NBC, and somewhat matches your description.

I watched a few episodes when I was a kid only because of Ann Jillian. It wasn't a great show otherwise.
Episodes are on YouTube.

From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085038/):

> The Elliots are a rich family that has just moved into the home of the late screen legend Jennifer Farrell. But Jennifer is still around... as a ghost that only their son Joey can see.

### Opening credits